# Get only file name from file input on internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html

I need to return only the file name from an HTML input file.

```
<input type="file" id="whatever" />
```

The JavaScript code im using to get the name of the file is:

```
document.getElementById("whatever").value;
```

In firefox it gives only the file name which is what I want, but in IE I get the full path.

I think that string manipulation is the only way to get the name.

What would be the easiest/shortest way to get only the name (extension too) in JavaScript? Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try this

```
var path = document.getElementById("whatever").value;
var fileName = path.match(/[^\/\\]+$/);
console.log(fileName);
```

Comment: Perfect, I think it can't be shorter than that.

Comment: I'm using `path.match(/[^\/\\]*$/)[0]`. 

1 - The result from the match isn't a `string`

2 - No errors if `path == ''`;

Answer (score 2):

I hope this works.

```
var fullFileName = document.getElementById("whatever").value;
var fileName = fullFileName.substr(fullFileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1, fullFileName.length);
```

Here is the fiddle for that [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bittu4u4ever/4NcjW/)

Comment: Ill try it here and tell you the result

Answer (score 0):

```
var path = document.getElementById("whatever").value;
var filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

This will give you everything after the last `/`, but is also compatible with a lack of `/`s.  In case you also need to deal with `\` as the lovely path separator, you can always use this first:

```
path.replace(/\\/g, "/")
```